# Pandas Dataframe get trend in column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, kaggle

I have a dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'day':[3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6],
                   'item': [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4],
                   'price':np.random.randint(1,30,11)})
```

```
   day item price
0   3   1   6
1   4   1   12
2   4   2   13
3   4   2   9
4   5   1   10
5   5   2   12
6   5   3   6
7   5   3   16
8   5   4   1
9   6   3   17
10  6   4   2
```

After the groupby code `gb = df1.groupby(['day','item'])['price'].mean()`, I get:

```
gb

     day  item
3    1        6
4    1       12
     2       11
5    1       10
     2       12
     3       11
     4        1
6    3       17
     4        2
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

I want to get the trend from the groupby series replacing back into the dataframe column price. The price is the variation of the item-price with repect to the previous day price

```
  day item  price
0   3   1   nan
1   4   1   6
2   4   2   nan
3   4   2   nan
4   5   1   -2
5   5   2   1
6   5   3   nan
7   5   3   nan
8   5   4   nan
9   6   3   6
10  6   4   1
```

Please help me to code the last step. A single/double line code will be most helpful. As the actual dataframe is huge, I would like to avoid iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
    #get the average values
    mean_df=df1.groupby(['day','item'])['price'].mean().reset_index()
    #rename columns 
    mean_df.columns=['day','item','average_price']
    #sort by day an item in ascending
    mean_df=mean_df.sort_values(by=['day','item'])
    #shift the price for each item and each day 
    mean_df['shifted_average_price'] = mean_df.groupby(['item'])['average_price'].shift(1)
    #combine with original df 
    df1=pd.merge(df1,mean_df,on=['day','item'])
    #replace the price by difference of previous day's 
    df1['price']=df1['price']-df1['shifted_average_price']
    #drop unwanted columns
    df1.drop(['average_price', 'shifted_average_price'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. shift(1) was the key. I missed it totally!

Comment: sure glad I could help also please accept it as an answer when you can .Thanks and happy coding